# Accessibility on react native nested text components

Tags: react-native, text, accessibility

From what I understand to create links in inline text the solution is too use nested text components like so (ps i know that using click me as a link is bad style I'm just trying to highlight the main issue)

```
<Text>
  To find out more
  <Text onClick={() => console.log('link was pressed')} accessibilityRole="button">
    Click me
  </Text>
</Text>
```

The onClick works but the accessibilityRole does not appear to work.

Comment: Unfortunately this is something React Native's accessibility API is really bad at. Similar question with one possible workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210049/how-can-i-make-a-link-in-a-nested-text-element-accessible-in-react-native